# My react router dom Redirect path is not working . Its not popping any error but is not making my home page to private Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've trying to make a private to my main dashboard i.e my home page to private and i created a new component called private route and redirected to login page if is not authenticated but is not redirecting .
I want to make it access to home page only if user can login and is authenticated
This is my Private Route

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthContext from '../../context/auth/authContext';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
    const {isAuthenticated, loading} = authContext;
    return (
       <Route {...rest}
        render={props => 
        !isAuthenticated && !loading ? (
           <Redirect to='/login' />
       ) : (
           <Component {...props} />
       )} />
    );
};

export default PrivateRoute
```

authContext.js

```
import {createContext} from 'react';

const authContext = createContext();

export default authContext;
```

setAuthToken.js

```
import axios from 'axios';


const setAuthToken = token => {
  if(token){
      axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = token;
  }else{
      delete axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'];
  }
}

export default setAuthToken;
```

This is my main app.js

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './component/layout/Navbar';
import Alerts from './component/layout/Alerts';
import Home from './component/pages/Home';
import About from './component/pages/About';
import Register from './component/auth/Register';
import Login from './component/auth/Login';
import PrivateRoute from './component/routing/PrivateRoute';

import ContactState from './context/contact/ContactState'
import AuthState from './context/auth/AuthState'
import AlertState from './context/alert/AlertState'
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken'
import './App.css';

if(localStorage.token){
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthState>
    <ContactState>
    <AlertState>
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
      <Alerts />
       <Switch>
         <PrivateRoute exact path = '/' component={Home} />
         <Route exact path = '/about' component={About} />
         <Route exact path = '/register' component={Register} />
         <Route exact path = '/login' component={Login} />
       </Switch>
     </div>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
    </AlertState>
    </ContactState>
    </AuthState>
  );
}

export default App;
```

login.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
import AlertContext from '../../context/alert/alertContext'
import AuthContext from '../../context/auth/authContext';

const Login = (props) => {
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
    const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext);

    const {setAlert} = alertContext
    const {login, error, clearErrors, isAuthenticated} = authContext;

    useEffect(()=> {
        if(isAuthenticated){
            props.history.push('/');
        }
        if(error === 'Invalid Credentials'){
           setAlert(error, 'danger');
           clearErrors();
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [error, isAuthenticated, props.history]); 

    const[user, setUser] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''  
    });

    const {email, password} = user;


    const onChange = e => setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
       if(email === '' || password=== ''){
           setAlert('Please fill in all fields', 'danger');
       }else{
           login({
               email,

           })
       }
    };


    return (
        <div className='form-container'>
        <h1>
            Account <span className="text-primary">Login</span>
        </h1>  
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" value={email} onChange={onChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" value={password} onChange={onChange} />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" className="btn btn-primary btn-block"/>
        </form>          
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

register.js

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import AlertContext from '../../context/alert/alertContext'
import AuthContext from '../../context/auth/authContext';


const Register = (props) => {
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
    const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext);

    const {setAlert} = alertContext
    const {register, error, clearErrors, isAuthenticated} = authContext;

    useEffect(()=> {
        if(isAuthenticated){
            props.history.push('/');
        }
        if(error === 'User already exists'){
           setAlert(error, 'danger');
           clearErrors();
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [error, isAuthenticated, props.history]); 
    const[user, setUser] = useState({ 
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        password2: ''
    });

    const {name, email, password, password2} = user;


    const onChange = e => setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(name === '' || email === ''|| password === ''){
            setAlert('please enter all fields', 'danger')
        }else if (password !== password2){
            setAlert('password do not match', 'danger');
        }else{
            register({
                name,
                email,
                password
            });
         }
    };


    return (
        <div className='form-container'>
        <h1>
            Account <span className="text-primary">Register</span>
        </h1>  
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={onChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" value={email} onChange={onChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" value={password} onChange={onChange} minLength="6" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password2">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password2" value={password2} onChange={onChange} minLength="6" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" className="btn btn-primary btn-block"/>
        </form>          
        </div>
    )
}

export default Register
```

authState.js

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';
import AuthContext from './authContext' 
import axios from 'axios';
import authReducer from './authReducer'
import setAuthToken from '../../utils/setAuthToken'
import {
    REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_FAIL,
    USER_LOADED,
    AUTH_ERROR,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
    LOGOUT,
    CLEAR_ERRORS
} from '../types'

const AuthState = props => {
    const initialstate = {
     token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
     isAuthenticated: null,
     loading: true,
     user: null,
     error: null
    };

    const  [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialstate);


    // Load user
    const loadUser = () => async () => {
       if(localStorage.token){
           setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
       }

        try {
            const res = await axios.get('/api/auth');
            dispatch({
                type: USER_LOADED,
                payload: res.data
            });
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR })
        }
    };

    // Register user
    const register = async formData => {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
        }
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('/api/users', formData, config);

            dispatch({
                type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            });
            loadUser();
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({ 
                type: REGISTER_FAIL,
                payload: error.response.data.msg
            })
        }
    }

    // Login user
    const login = async formData => {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
        }
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('/api/auth', formData, config);

            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            });
            loadUser();
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({ 
                type: LOGIN_FAIL,
                payload: error.response.data.msg
            });
        }
    }

    // Logout
    const logout = () => dispatch({type: LOGOUT});

    // Clear errors
    const clearErrors = () => dispatch({type: CLEAR_ERRORS });




    return  (
        <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
           token: state.token,
           isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
           loading: state.loading,
           user: state.user,
           error: state.error,
           register,
           loadUser,
           login,
           logout,
           clearErrors 
        }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default AuthState;
```

authreducer.js

```
import {
    REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_FAIL,
    USER_LOADED,
    AUTH_ERROR,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
    LOGOUT,
    CLEAR_ERRORS,

} from '../types'

export default (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
    case USER_LOADED:
        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            loading: false,
            user: action.payload
        }
     case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
     case LOGIN_SUCCESS:    
         localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
         return {
          ...state,
          ...action.payload,
          isAuthenticated: true,
          loading: false
         };
         case REGISTER_FAIL:
         case AUTH_ERROR:   
         case LOGIN_FAIL: 
         case LOGOUT:
             localStorage.removeItem('token');
             return {
                 ...state,
                 token: null,
                 isAuthenticated: false,
                 loading: false,
                 user: null,
                 error: action.payload
             };
             case CLEAR_ERRORS:
                 return {
                     ...state,
                     error: null
                 }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `setAuthToken`? have you confirmed that `isAuthenticated` is already true

may be you can put your full code on codesandbox, it will be easier to find the problem

**UPDATE**

You should read token from local storage and update isAuthenticated boolean in AuthContext when page initial load.

after user logout, token must be clear and set `isAuthenticated` to `false`.

```
import {createContext} from 'react';

const token = localStorage.token;

const authContext = createContext({
  isAuthenticated: token !== null && token !== 'undefined' && token !== '',
  loading: false,
});

export default authContext;
```

Comment: i have added setauth token file too .. how can i put a full code directly ??

Comment: you can put on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard/recent).

Comment: I read your code, your authContext is not implement, so `isAuthenticated` is always `false` right?

Comment: its sttill not working i,ve updated my login.js too help me out

Comment: your login flow looks fine. what are `USER_LOADED` and `LOGIN_SUCCESS` action doing? please add `authReducer`

Comment: i have added   do check out and let me know . i've been stuck in it from 3 days

Comment: sorry, I'm a little busy these days, did you solve it? If not, please put your project on cloud IDE such as [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) so that I can quickly see the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is in `AuthContext`? Your usage of `useContext` looks conspicuous to me but it depends on what `AuthContext` is, and that's what's controlling whether or not you hit the `Redirect`.